# UnityScript to C# in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code written in UnityScript. I need to write it in C#. When I use an online converter there seems to be a compiler error. What is the problem?

It is going to be used to display a text for 3 seconds in UI Text. I am new to Unity, so I might not have explained well.

UnityScript code:

```js
private var timer: float;
private var showTime: float;
private var activeTimer: boolean;
private var message: String;
private var uiText: UI.Text;

function startTimer()
{
    timer = 0.0f;
    showTime = 3.0f;
    uiText.text = message;
    activeTimer = true;
}

function Start()
{
    uiText = GetComponent(UI.Text);
}

function Update()
{
    if (activeTimer)
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (timer > showTime)
        {
            activeTimer = false;
            uiText.text = "";
        }
    }
}

function showText(m: String)
{
    message = m;
    startTimer();
}
```

The output from C# Converter that seems to have some problem:

```
private float timer;
private float showTime;
private bool  activeTimer;
private string message;
private UI.Text uiText;

void startTimer()
{
    timer = 0.0ff;
    showTime = 3.0ff;
    uiText.text = message;
    activeTimer = true;
}

void Start()
{
    uiText = GetComponent<UI.Text>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (activeTimer)
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (timer > showTime)
        {
            activeTimer = false;
            uiText.text = "";
        }
    }
}

void showText(string m)
{
    message = m;
    startTimer();
}
```

Comment: Your float value for timer and showtime should be 0.0f, and 3.0f. You have "ff", which is not valid. Additionally, you do not have a class defined for all of the methods in the script. If this all encompassed in a public class that derives from monobehaviour? Other than that, if you can provide the error you see in your console when you try to run the script, that will prove useful.

Comment: I have tried with 0.0f and 3.0f. Still nothing changed. The main problem is I can't play the scene because it says "All compiler errors have to be fixed before you enter playmode". And without this code, I could enter play mode.

Comment: You need to share the errors. They will be displayed in the console line by line, highlighting the lines in your code that have syntax errors.

Comment: I use NotePad++ to open cs file. And in Unity console there doesn't appear any error or something.  [This](https://i.hizliresim.com/Xbj587.png) is the problem that occurs when I click play button.

Comment: Change your tab from "Project" to "Console" and share another screenshot.

Comment: I dont think it changes as I click play button. But [sure](https://i.hizliresim.com/00aQXY.png)

Comment: Turn off the "Standard" messages, and turn on console error messages by clicking the little red "!" button on the console window.

Comment: [Here](https://i.hizliresim.com/6DE0L9.png)

Comment: Change "UI.Text" to "Text" when defining your uiText property.

Comment: It would be a good idea to spend some time learning to use Unity's debugging tools, and probably using a proper IDE for C# development. Notepad++ is a very poor tool for compiled languages.

Comment: Visual Studio is the standard. If you double click on a script in Unity and you have visual studio installed, it will automatically open in VS and will have integrated intellisense.

Comment: @Herohtar Its actually UnityScript, which is and isn't JS. Which is why it has its own tag, but 99% the same as JavaScript with the extra addons for the Unity engine.

Comment: @FuadShahmuradov In the future, please don't put "SOLVED" in the question title.

Comment: @Herohtar Okay, but why? I thought I saw some people do it, and thought it should be the way it is done.

Comment: Because that [is not the correct thing to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116101/381439). There shouldn't be any questions that actually have solved in the title. Some people might do it, but it will pretty quickly be edited out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a C# script you have to derive from MonoBehaviour. The script below will work =)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

/// <summary>
/// Display a text for 3 seconds in UI Text.
/// </summary>
class DisplayText : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float timer;
    private float showTime;
    private bool activeTimer;
    private string message;
    private Text uiText;

    void Start()
    {
        uiText = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (activeTimer)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (timer > showTime)
            {
                activeTimer = false;
                uiText.text = "";
            }
        }
    }

    void startTimer()
    {
        timer = 0.0f;
        showTime = 3.0f;
        uiText.text = message;
        activeTimer = true;
    }

    void showText(string m)
    {
        message = m;
        startTimer();
    }
}
```